# How to dump heap to s3 using HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, heap-memory, amazon-emr, oom

I am trying to dump a heap file from spark(EMR) to s3 bucket using

```
new SparkConf().set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=s3://my-bucket/logs/heapDumps/executor/my_heap_dump.hprof")
```

However following error log appeared.

```
Dumping heap to s3://my-bucket/logs/heapDumps/executor/my_heap_dump.hprof ...
Unable to create s3://my-bucket/logs/heapDumps/executor/my_heap_dump.hprof: No such file or directory
```

Does spark.driver.extraJavaOptions accept s3 bucket location as a valid argument? I tried to save it in the local directory, but it seems tidious since masterNode is not opened public and I have to access to EC2 which the executor  is running.  I'm also using EMR, so it would be nicer if I could leverage up these AWS services

I would like to know if there is a way to dump heap logs directly from EMR to s3 bucket.

FYI, I have already created s3 bucket `my-bucket/logs/heapDumps/executor`

Answer (score 0):

> Does spark.driver.extraJavaOptions accept s3 bucket location as a valid argument?

The question is really "does XX:HeapDumpPath accept an s3 bucket location as a valid argument?"

no, not unless somehow it is mounted as a linux filesystem. The pure-java APIs for reading/writing data talk to the local FS and things mounted there (nfs drives etc). That is completely different from the FileSystems which spark, hive etc can work with, to which they connect to through filesystem client classes which must be on the classpath and configured with binding and authentication informationm